# Heroku Redirect non-www to www on Django website

Tags: django, heroku

I currently have a website domain with Bluehost.
Bluehost cannot redirect https://example.com to https://www.example.com using 301 redirects since I am not hosting with them. Now in my DNS settings, I have a `CNAME (Alias)` record that points **@** to `<string1>.herokudns.com` and I have another `CNAME (Alias)` that points **www** to `<string2>.herokudns.com`. Please note that I have SSL certificate and both are on HTTPS.

I have contacted Bluehost and they said one solution would be to point both **www** and **@** to `<string1>.herokudns.com` but that does not seem to be a redirection to me.

How can I manage to redirect the naked domain to **www** within Heroku on Python? I cannot test them a lot since Bluehost TTL is 4 hours and I cannot manage to change my configurations fast.

Appreciate any help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to follow this link:

https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/03/02/how-to-make-django-redirect-www-to-your-bare-domain/

And I customized it like:

```
from django.http import HttpResponsePermanentRedirect


class WwwRedirectMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        host = request.get_host().partition(':')[0]
        if host == "example.com":
            return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(
                "https://www.example.com" + request.path
            )
        else:
            return self.get_response(request)
```

I have tested it and it currently works! I'd still appreciate any feedback on this method!